# « Toutes les filles trouvent cet homme de leur type » est-elle une phrase correcte?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

Toutes les filles trouvent cet homme de leur type.

Ou

Cet homme est le type de toutes les filles.

Ou serait-ce mieux de dire « Toutes les filles trouvent cet homme attirant » ou « Toutes les filles le veulent ».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Je proposerais bien « Toutes les filles trouvent cet homme à leur goût » ou « Cet homme plait à toutes les filles ».