# « Trouver quelqu'un, quelque chose à son goût » avec la préposition « de » (...de son goût) ?

Tags: prépositions, expressions-idiomatiques, fréquence-utilisation

Dans une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/50807/26366) on [répond](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/50816/26366) avec l'expression « trouver qqn, qqch à son goût » qu'on trouve au [lexique](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/go%C3%BBt/37667#156360). Mais historiquement ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=trouver%20%C3%A0%20son%20go%C3%BBt%2Ctrouver%20de%20son%20go%C3%BBt&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctrouver%20%C3%A0%20son%20go%C3%BBt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrouver%20de%20son%20go%C3%BBt%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctrouver%20%C3%A0%20son%20go%C3%BBt%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctrouver%20de%20son%20go%C3%BBt%3B%2Cc0)) on semble avoir un chevauchement entre un emploi avec la préposition *à* et un autre avec le préposition *de* (*...de son goût*) ; si on voit qu'au début du 20e l'emploi avec *à* prend le dessus, on voit qu'au 21e cet emploi déclasse de beaucoup plus celui avec *de*. J'ai (Montréal) une hésitation mais je suis plus familier avec l'emploi avec *de*.

Trouve-t-on l'emploi avec la préposition « de » vieilli ou complètement inusité, est-il régional ; qu'est-ce qui explique qu'au 21e siècle la courbe du *ngram* prend un envol marqué, est-ce simplement qu'on emploie davantage la locution ?

Answer (score 2):

Pour ma part, en France, je n’ai jamais lu ou entendu l’expression « trouver […] de son goût ». Mais si c’est vieilli, ça ne me surprend pas plus que ça que ce soit en usage dans les régions francophones du Canada ; il me semble que le français qui y est parlé est plus « traditionaliste » que celui qui est parlé en France (en praticulier pour ce qui est du rejet des anglicismes).